# How to fill the background of a cropped image

Tags: python, opencv

At the moment I have an image that I crop in OpenCV with the given x,y coordinates. I'm trying to detect the white pixels on said image and display them. The code works fine but on some frames of the example video I'm using to make screenshots, the crop background includes elements with white in it aswell.

I have the following code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Image_crop.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 150,255,0)
gray2 = gray.copy()

cv2.imshow('IMG',gray2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Crop output:

[image: crop output]

White pixel output:

[image: white pixel output]

Wanted output:

[image: wanted output]

Is there a way to fill the background of the cropped image or get the wanted output?

Comment: don't expect grabcut to work flawlessly. it doesn't know what it sees. it reacts to edges and color ranges and that's it. -- just define a mask once, manually (in an image editor). you don't need any algorithms for this because the mask never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not as easy as it looks. The simple solution could be using `cv2.grabCut` ( [Sample](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/07/27/opencv-grabcut-foreground-segmentation-and-extraction/) tutorial ) , but it is not going to get you perfect results.

Instead of cropping the image at first, give the boundary to `cv2.grabCut`, mask the background and crop the image afterward.

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg') 
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

rect = (x, y, width, height) # boundary of interest
cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
img = img * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]

# crop the image and ...
```

If the input is video, you could increase your performance using object tracking algorithms.

Comment: Thank you this works for me, there's still a bit of white around the edges on the left side, any way this can be removed or is this bound to happen with grabcut?

Comment: The grabcut or any other algorithm could not perfectly separate foreground and background in all case. You could try to use intuitive method for your specific task . for example if you know that what you want is always in middle or always specific shapes or ... you could increase the accuracy.

Comment: Yeah thought so, I''ll try looking into it then but for now this looks good, thanks